# Jquery value undefined with dynamic drop down menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to build a string with two values per array value - search term and if it's =, > etc. I've got it so far that i populate the ID value perfectly but when i try to get the value via the ID of the dropdown as well i get an undifined error. Anyone got an idea on what i've missed off? Thanks

HTML Code

```
<span>Where ID  </span><input name="ctl00$cBody$[ID]" type="text" id="[ID]" class="querysearch" runat="server" name="ID" /><select name="ctl00$cBody$[ID0]" id="[ID0]" class="querysearchtype">
        <option value="=">=</option>
        <option value=">">&gt;</option>
        <option value="&lt;">&lt;</option>
        <option value="&lt;>">&lt;&gt;</option>
        <option value="=&lt;">=&lt;</option>
        <option value="=>">=&gt;</option>

    </select>
```

Jquery Code

```
$('#lnkBuildWhereQuery').click(function () {
          var toPost = '';
          var stype = ' WHERE ';
          var rcount = 0
          $("#wherequery").val("")
          $('.querysearch').each(function () {
              if (rcount != 0) {
                  stype = " AND "
              };

              if (!this.value) {
                  //Blank Value Searched
              }
              else {
                  //Build dropdown id by id of textbox
                  var qid = ($(this).attr('id'))
                  //Add the dynamic number and replace the end ] to stop [id]0 - should be [id0]
                  var qidrename = "#" + qid.replace("]", rcount + "]")
                  //Stick it all together to get the value of dropdwon by id"#"
                  var qidval = $(qidrename).val()
                  //var qidval = " ="
                  toPost = toPost + stype + $(this).attr('id') + qidval + " '" + $(this).val() + '\'';
             $("#wherequery").val(toPost);
             rcount = rcount + 1}

         });
     });
```

Problem part:

```
var qidval = $(qidrename).val()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use id attribute to match not by # like,

```
$('[id=yourID]')
```

here in code need to replace the lines accordingly as

instead of

```
var qidrename = "#" + qid.replace("]", rcount + "]")
```

try

```
var qidrename = '[id="'+qid.replace("]", rcount + "]")+'"]';
```

Comment: Thank you very much - fixed my issue!

Comment: for using special characters need to escape or match with the id attr. glad it helps